# How to use programmatically defined font in storyboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I have so many UILabels and buttons in storyboard in a same style And I also have a list of fonts like

```
#define FLOAT_F1  [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]
#define FLOAT_F2  [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]
```

Can I use these defines in storyboard?So that I don't have to change it one by one in storyboard if the standards is changed.

Comment: No, though you can create a `CustomLabel` class which inherits from `UILabel`. Just change the font in the `awakeFromNib` method and set that class in storyboard.

Comment: but,it's also complicated for me,#_#,thanks and I'll try to find another way.

Comment: It's super easy. It's exactly what Jayesh posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom Label as shown below.

**File : UICustomLabel.h**

```
@interface UICustomLabel : UILabel

@end
```

**File : UICustomLabel.m**

```
@implementation UICustomLabel
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {

        // [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" size:self.font.pointSize]
        [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@“Font_Name" size:self.font.pointSize]];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Then assign class UICustomLabel to each label in all storyboard you require to set as shown below.

[image: Set Custom Class To Label]

This will work for you. Please let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Thanks,it's worked,but not perfect,for example,I have to custom 5 labels if I need 5 kinds of font in a view.

Comment: No, If you have 5 custom labels you can make five different kind of custom label classes in single class and then you can use that class.

Comment: This should be the right way,I'll classify my labels.